# How to send list of objects through POST mapping using Postman?

Tags: java, json, postman

I am using Postman  to send a post request with the following controller (which doesn't work)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateData", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public int updateData(@RequestBody FriendInfoForm request);
```

and I want this type of payload to be accepted as a "request" object.

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 27,
    "friendList": [
        {
            "name": "Jack",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Jill",
            "age": 21
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is the `FriendInfoForm` definition:

```
public class FriendInfoForm {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private ArrayList friendList;
    (getters and setters)
}
```

When I try to send the post request, `name` and `age` get set correctly, but `friendList` doesn't (it doesn't get set to anything). I can guess why (has to do with the Arraylist use).

How do I send it correctly?

Comment: You should create a `Friend` type with name and age properties then change the type of `FriendInfoForm.friendList` to `ArrayList<Friend>`.

Comment: gotcha, thank you! Sometimes the simple solution is best

Answer (score 0):

you should create POJO like below class:--

```
public class FriendInfoForm {
    
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @JsonProperty("friendList")
    private List<FriendList> friendList = new ArrayList<>();;
    (getters and setters)
}

public class FriendList{
 private String name;
    private int age;
(getters and setters)
}
}
```